# ibm watson webhook without ibm cloud function

Tags: ibm-cloud, webhooks, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, ibm-cloud-functions

Please is it possible to use a specific rest API, in IBM Watson webhook, without using IBM Cloud Function.
I want to develop a rest API with nodeJs and expose it to be used in webhook call Url(IBM Assistant)
Hear what I have done:
I tried to use the same content that I have in could function, i exposed it in my server nodeJS, but it doesn't work.

Please have you an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [overview page in the documentation of IBM Watson Assistant on where you can use webhooks](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-webhook-overview). Initially, some years back, Watson Assistant / Watson Conversation only allowed webhooks based on IBM Cloud Functions. But that has changed long ago.

Thus, you can configure webhooks that are not based on Cloud Functions. For dialog skills, the [requirements are shown here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-webhooks#dialog-webhooks-create):

- The call must be a POST HTTP request.
- The request body must be a JSON object (Content-Type: application/json).
- The response must be a JSON object (Accept: application/json).
- The call must return in 8 seconds or less.

Comment: thanks, i have done the same thing, but i had missed the Content-Type in response API. i thought that watson will intercept the content